# loop or apply to generate percentile value in new column for each existing column in df

Tags: r, loops, iteration, percentile

I'd like to generate a "percentile in the distribution" column for each existing column.

I'm unsure how to generate this percentile column for an individual series, though.

```
#generate data
df <- data.frame(rnorm(100, 3, 1.2),
                     rnorm(100, 2, 0.5),
                     rnorm(100, 4, 1.5),
                     rnorm(100, 5, 0.2),
                     rnorm(100, 6, 0.7))
    colnames(df) <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')

#failed attempt to generate new column
df$a_pct <- sapply(df$a, function(x) ecdf(x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ecdf` of value returns a function.

```
str(ecdf(df$a))
#function (v)  
#- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "ecdf" "stepfun" "function"
#- attr(*, "call")= language ecdf(df$a)
```

To get the percentiles, apply the function on the values i.e.

```
ecdf(df$a)(df$a)
```

and for multiple columns, loop through the columns with `lapply/sapply`

```
res1 <-  sapply(df, function(x) ecdf(x)(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use `ecdf`? Just do:

```
sapply(df, function(x) rowMeans(outer(x, x, `>`)))
```